# DNS Resolve is not working on 18.04 server

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, dns

I have done some fairly extensive searching and can't seem to find the needle in the haystack that fixes this issue.

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I am running LXC/LXD on the server currently with only a single container which is actually a 16.04 image. DNS works fine from within the container. I believe this eliminates any potential network issue as the problem.

In the 18.04 install the following happens when using nslookup

```
nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

However when including a dns server directly as such I get a lookup to work. Again seemingly ruling out firewall/network issues

```
nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.5.238
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:802::200e
```

As part of following tips/tricks/guides some of the following things I tried are below, as well as various outputs that might be useful in helping nail this down.

I modified the following file to look as such. I only added the name servers. I did this following one of the fixes out there.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    ens3:
        dhcp4: true
        match:
            macaddress: <redacted for post>
        set-name: ens3
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.0.0]
```

This did seem to add the dns servers to the device

```
sudo systemd-resolve --status
Global
      DNS Domain: openstacklocal
      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
                  168.192.in-addr.arpa
                  17.172.in-addr.arpa
                  18.172.in-addr.arpa
                  19.172.in-addr.arpa
                  20.172.in-addr.arpa
                  21.172.in-addr.arpa
                  22.172.in-addr.arpa
                  23.172.in-addr.arpa
                  24.172.in-addr.arpa
                  25.172.in-addr.arpa
                  26.172.in-addr.arpa
                  27.172.in-addr.arpa
                  28.172.in-addr.arpa
                  29.172.in-addr.arpa
                  30.172.in-addr.arpa
                  31.172.in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  d.f.ip6.arpa
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test

Link 5 (vethTR4JCU)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (lxdbr0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (ens3)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 8.8.4.4
                      8.8.8.8
                      1.1.1.1
                      1.1.0.0
                      <redacted for post>
         DNS Domain: openstacklocal
```

Even with the dns servers listed there, no lookups are possible using either dig, or nslookup.

I did install resolvconf as part of a guide, though I think that was unnecessary and just proved to make a bigger mess.

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 29 12:55 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search openstacklocal
```

This is as far as I seem to be able to get. If I add valid nameservers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 1.1.1.1, etc) to /run/resolveconf/resolv.conf file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8   # manually added in for testing
search openstacklocal
```

I can get lookups to work as shown below. If course as is stated in the file, these changes are overwritten on reboot.

```
nslookup google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.15.78
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4004:810::200e
```

EDIT: output of apply command

```
sudo netplan --debug apply
** (generate:15710): DEBUG: 14:11:34.829: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:15710): DEBUG: 14:11:34.830: starting new processing pass
** (generate:15710): DEBUG: 14:11:34.878: ens3: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:15710): DEBUG: 14:11:34.879: Generating output files..
** (generate:15710): DEBUG: 14:11:34.879: NetworkManager: definition ens3 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration exists, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:ens3 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: <redacted for post>
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.4.4
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 1.1.0.0
      set-name: ens3
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:device ens3 operstate is up, not changing
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lxdbr0
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: vethTR4JCU
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for ens3
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lxdbr0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethTR4JCU
```

EDIT: Requsted

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ens3   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 /* allow connection to lxd */
 2336  152K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxdbr0 *       10.100.106.40        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
 1279 73342 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8207 2604K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
 9496 3318K ACCEPT     all  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70 packets, 8606 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
```

Anyone know the link/solution to this problem. I'm at a loss.

Comment: See my answer askubuntu.com/questions/1113360/… Try adding the libnss-resolve package. The other workaround to the bugs listed (do add yourself to the bug "does this affect me?" list) is to use the nameserver(s) directly, cutting systemd-resolv out of the loop by changing /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: are you able to contact local DNS cache? output of `iptables -L -n -v`?

Comment: Updated question with requested output

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: allow port 53 tcp & udp to lo interface.

Even though the default policy on INPUT is ACCEPT, there is a final rule that drops anything not yet accepted. The only rules accepting traffic on port 53 are on the lxdbr0 interface. You could blanket allow everything on `lo` interface or just allow ports as needed.

To push a rule to allow everything on lo interface ahead of the other rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that rule. It's even in my notes! Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I went down the same path Dave did, but I am not having a problem with my iptables...  This is fantastically hard to debug now

Comment: I stumbled with the same and solved it by strict syntax in the /etc/netplan/99-netcfg-vmware.yaml: I added spaces around the nameservers and before the square brackets like this:  `addresses: [ 10.103.4.50,10.103.4.51 ]` instead of `addresses: [10.103.4.50,10.103.4.51]`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the answer - or how this could have solved Daves problem: in Dave's INPUT chain, there is an ACCEPT anything rule - two lines above the mentioned DROP anything rule. This rule should also have accepted packets for "lo" port 53.
Can anyone please explain? Thanx.

Comment: It's been a few years and I don't remember, but I think there was something funny about the wildcard not matching the loopback interface.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly the only correct answer to this modern b***** was to :

```
apt remove ifupdown
apt install cloud-init
# comment out settings in /etc/network/interfaces
# complete settings in /etc/netplan/config.yaml

# Apply settings or reboot
netplan apply
```

The removal of `ifupdown` is needed to make the DNS resolver function properly.

Comment: cloud-init was missing...but not missing somehow for me

Comment: Yep. Worked for me after about a year of suffering intermittently DNS during which nothing else has ever worked. See [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1259533/269136) which was never resolved. I didn't comment out any settings, just installed cloud-init and removed ifupdown then did `netplan apply`.

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I had this same issue. Tried the above plus many other solutions that revolved around the resolv.conf.

My true culprit: POSTFIX. Somehow/someway postfix was interfering with my DNS configuration. After removing postfix with the --auto-remove, magically the DNS started to resolve again.

I can now ping and apt-get again. What a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 mysteriously disabled systemd-resolved service. Fix was a matter of enabling it again.

Answer (score 0):

After you have changed to NetPlan configuration. Run

```
sudo netplan apply
```

To expand the changes.
To evaluate the changes, execute:

```
sudo netplan --debug apply
```

**Update with more information.**

I have this file configuration: `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

The parameters that you put are correct.
Why not try:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

PS: make a backup.

Comment: Those were done when I made the changes.

Comment: Made no difference. I didn't think it would as the configuration file is actually being picked up and used as shown in the added domain server output. There seems to be a disconnect between the resolv 127.0.0.53 and the actual nameservers. I'm just not sure how that's supposed to work to even know how to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to apply the Netplan configuration again. After an update on one of my docker nodes I lost the DNS resolution and just used the command below to re-apply the network configuration on the server:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Everything worked as expected after that.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Dave's post.  I started having this issue after installing postfix and did not want to uninstall postfix.

I found that adding 8.8.8.8 to resolv.conf as mentioned was a temporary fix, but then i found that it wasn't even necessary.
**The fix that worked for me, believe it or not, was simply to add a blank line before 127.0.0.53 in resolv.conf.**