# DNS lookups fail on 18.04 host: trying to resolve from 127.0.0.1:53 but resolvd is listening on 127.0.0.53:53

Tags: dns, docker, systemd-resolved

My 18.04 can't do name lookups.

I have a problem similar to the one described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113901/dns-resolve-is-not-working-on-18-04-server) question, but the answer there didn't help me.

```
nslookup --verbose google.com
;; Connection to 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) for google.com failed: connection refused
;; Connection to ::1#53(::1) for google.com failed: connection refused

nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
<works>

nslookup google.com 127.0.0.53
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.0.46
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4005:807::200e
```

In addition, nslookup works from inside Docker containers.

```
systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 7 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 5 (wlp4s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 2001:558:feed::1
                      2001:558:feed::2
                      192.168.0.1

Link 4 (eno2)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      2001:558:feed::1
                      2001:558:feed::2

Link 2 (enp7s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

```
 sudo netstat -lntup
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4212/sendmail: MTA: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7074/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5892/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43128         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8791/code           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4212/sendmail: MTA: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9150          0.0.0.0:*                       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12607         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6531/code           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/slapd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      5892/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN      2277/slapd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           3636/chrome         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           3636/chrome         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           3636/chrome         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1012/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46376           0.0.0.0:*                           1012/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           7074/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           5195/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           5147/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           5893/cups-browsed   
udp6       0      0 :::34949                :::*                                1012/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                3636/chrome         
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                3636/chrome         
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1012/avahi-daemon:
```

I notice that nothing is listening on 127.0.0.1:53, and systemd-resolv is listening on 127.0.0.53:53. So why is nslookup trying to hit 127.0.0.1:53? If I force nslookup to 127.0.0.53:53 it works. How do I configure my system to always use that address for name lookups?

Here is my full iptable:

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8502 1958K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 7055  559K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
18180 8978K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 8938  570K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10662 2525K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10662 2525K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10662 2525K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
10662 2525K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
18591   29M DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
18591   29M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10993   29M ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 7598  402K ACCEPT     all  --  br-cea5793d9738 !br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-cea5793d9738 br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13288 packets, 2752K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
43767 5406K OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-cea5793d9738 br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:5006
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-cea5793d9738 br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:5001
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-cea5793d9738 br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 7598  402K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-cea5793d9738 !br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
18591   29M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-cea5793d9738  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 7598  402K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
18591   29M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  wlp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      wlp4s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      eno1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 4163  994K IN_public  all  --  wlp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
 4310 1030K IN_public  all  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
  142 12206 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
10662 2525K IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10662 2525K IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10662 2525K IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Here is my full ifconfig:

```
br-cea5793d9738: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:71ff:feb0:158b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:71:b0:15:8b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7600  bytes 401561 (401.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11163  bytes 28814006 (28.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:4f:1b:74:41  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.112  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::72da:47f4:adff:f338  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2601:647:4500:32b3:9705:b02f:2b66:35ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2601:647:4500:32b3:71e6:d21f:f3d:95c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether e0:d5:5e:ae:36:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 38746  bytes 41301178 (41.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19218  bytes 2729993 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xd8e00000-d8efffff  

eno2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:d5:5e:ae:36:55  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xd8b00000-d8bfffff  

enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:d5:5e:ae:36:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 39605  bytes 5884040 (5.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 39605  bytes 5884040 (5.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth8f2b71a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::dc3a:2bff:fe1b:ccd0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether de:3a:2b:1b:cc:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7600  bytes 507961 (507.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11129  bytes 28809099 (28.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethc4e5521: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::14da:8bff:fe5b:ff5c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 16:da:8b:5b:ff:5c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143  bytes 20703 (20.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2601:647:4500:32b3:e136:3d60:54f1:b370  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::d8c6:4a:4826:5711  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2601:647:4500:32b3:8b6:96b5:ef7b:1ea9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 94:b8:6d:b2:bb:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6795  bytes 1552450 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 528  bytes 93736 (93.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me days to find this, but the answer for me was here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1317623/nslookup-failed-but-systemd-resolved-works

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This happened to me with Ubuntu 22.04, GlobalProtect VPN from PaloAlto Networks is removing my link and replacing it by it files with VPN DNS, this helped me to solve the problem, thanks.