# No DNS lookup with Google's DNS servers

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

Some mornings when my Ubuntu 18.04 wakes from hibernate, it takes around 30 minutes before I can do any DNS lookups.

I already disabled automatic DNS and added Google's DNS servers instead:

[image: DNS Settings]

[image: How I set up Google's DNS servers]

But nevertheless, I can ping `8.8.8.8` but not `google.com`:

[image: can't ping Google]

Usually after much fruitless enabling/disabling Wifi, and connect and disconnecting Wifi networks, it suddenly springs into action and all is well for the rest of the day.

But here's the mystery: if Ubuntu is using `8.8.8.8` as its DNS lookup, how can it be the case that I can ping the IP but not the URL?

### dig

Here's the output of `dig`:

```
➜  dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39427
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         297     IN      A       216.58.206.100

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 20 19:52:43 BST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

## tcpdump

```
sudo tcpdump -ni lo port 53
```

This command showed nothing until about 20 minutes after booting up, at which point it exploded into life with things like:

[image: tcpdump]

## netstat

```
netstat -acpn | grep ":53"
```

This is the output of `netstat` when DNS lookup isn't working.

[image: netstat no DNS output]

And with DNS working, later in the day:

[image: netstat with DNS output]

Comment: just a note, 8.8.8.8 is not google.com... at least not the page you are thinking... It is https://dns.google.com... google.com would be the IP returned in the dig - 216.58.206.100... Though, the fact remains that you still cannot ping google.com... So does google.com even allow pings? I'm not able to test that from my location.

Comment: Yes @WU-TANG I can ping google.com when all is working normally.

Comment: random tests: is it only google.com? try yahoo.com or askubuntu.com. Does it only get fixed when you mess with it? Leave an open ping with sound `ping -a yahoo.com`and go about your day, until you hear it, then rush back and check your logs to see if anything just registered. Look at the traffic `sudo tcpdump -n port 53` is the traffic going out without a return? `netstat -acpn | grep ":53"` shows if a stub listener is running, if so, you'd probably have to `sudo tcpdump -ni lo port 53` to watch the requests the stub us handling. Wired connection behavior? Static IP? right after reboot?

Comment: @WU-TANG Thanks for sticking with this mysterious and very annoying problem. Next time it happens I'll try all these things. (I like the idea of `ping` actually making a ping sound. Didn't know that was an option.)

Comment: @WU-TANG added netstat and tcpdump outputs.

Comment: it looks like you are running both ipv4 and ipv6?

Comment: @WU-TANG I certainly haven't touched any of Ubuntu's defaults with regard to ipv6. Should I have done?

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but i'm just wondering why you show a secure(SSL) connection by firefox... it seems to be from your computer (Sky provider?) to Canonical group limited (i'm assuming ubuntu)... Maybe your ipv6 resolution is not working??? I would try disabling all ipv6 parameters on the interfaces if you are not intentionally using them. Go to the ipv6 tab, on the pictures you have above, and "disable" or "ignore" them for all of your interfaces, wifi and connected. Restart & see how it behaves. Now, I say all of this assuming ipv6 is NOT the norm yet over there??? Do you know?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I don't need ipv6 for anything @WU-TANG. I'll give it a try next time I'm in this position.

Comment: I'd disable it before then(before you see the problem)... and then see if your morning routine changes... I'd be curious to know if you lose internet completely if you disabled it during normal use... I've only done ipv6 on my local LAN so I don't know how 4 and 6 play together WAN-wise. – also you have DNS entries in your GUI, but you have "automatic ON" selected. I'm not sure how that is designed to behave (whether it overrides or not), I'd look into what effect that is having, those settings are on both ipv4 and ipv6. You, possibly, have a lot of variables. I cant test these, sorry.

Comment: This now appears to have been solved by [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255405/269136).

Comment: I'm glad you got it working better, but I don't quite understand... Are you running ubuntu server? I am not using netplan and I dont have cloud-init installed...  I think in the process of what you uninstalled and installed, that something else got fixed by some related action. Those two things aren't necessary to get DNS working on a vanilla system... but, as long as you have been dealing with it, i'm sure you'll take it.

Comment: @WU-TANG yes you were right. The steps I took following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255405/269136) seem to have worked only as a coincidence. The problem is still just as troubling as it always was.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.ubuntu.com
```

just to rule out that DNS traffic somehow gets mangled.

edit: dig is a tool to query DNS-Servers. By using the the @serverIP syntax you can bypass the systems DNS settings and directly talk to a DNS server of your choice. IMHO this helps a lot in diagnosing if the problem is your machine (dig with @syntax working) or on the network side (dig with @syntax returning the same result)

Comment: Thanks Sph! It didn't happen this morning, but next time it does, I'll try this. Didn't know about `dig`. Care to add anything to your answer which puts what `dig` does and why it'd be useful to know its output?

Comment: I can now confirm that this `dig` command works when dns doesn't work! Looks like you're onto something...

Comment: This might've been a one-off but last time this happened, I found an IP address from dig, put it into my browser and the whole DNS thing sprang into life. Not sure which logs to look in to see what had changed, but I'll try it again next time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to conflicts between the ancient system (ifupdown) and the new system (netplan,cloud-init,etc..). To only correct answer I could find to this modern nonsense was to :

```
apt remove ifupdown
apt install cloud-init
# comment out settings in /etc/network/interfaces
# complete settings in /etc/netplan/config.yaml

# Apply settings or reboot
netplan apply
```

**The removal of `ifupdown` is needed to make the DNS resolver function properly.**

*[nb: my original post here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1255405/45849]*

Comment: I don't really understand what `cloud-init` has to do with this solution. Is it related?

Comment: @LondonRob It is related to netplan, and installed by default on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling systemd-resolved and then checking how the resolution works? I had problems in the past with it.

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

Then in the [main] section of your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
dns=default
```

Delete symlink to resolv.conf

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

And then restart

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past this problem by forcing `resolved` to use a particular DNS server.

Previously, my `resolv.conf` was linked to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`:

```bsh
$ l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mar 30 10:32 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

This contained the following:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

(It also has a lot of comments about how the file is autogenerated and not to mess with it manually. I don't know *how* it got generated like that.)

So I created a separate `resolv.conf` file, with:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options edns0
```

and replaced my symlink. Then restarted the service with:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

and suddenly it all sprang into life.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to dictate DNS address. Since the DNS toggle is switched to automatic you can leave the field empty.

Comment: Hi! Can you explain what this means? Which field? What's a DNS toggle? Why does it mean I can leave the DNS unspecified?

Comment: This means your machine will automatically mimic the internet provider's DNS. Once you are connected to internet access.in most cases this results to 8.8.8.8 0r 8.8.4.4 which are both google DNS servers.

Comment: DNS Toggle refers to the button where yo switch on the  DNS to automatic mode on and off.. and yes you can leave the DNS unspecified